# Can I use G theory for this case? How? Comparing Waldorf and traditional schools

Tags: reliability

I have my data in the format of:

[image]

In my study I examined 20 waldorf student and 30 traditional student using concept map. Concept maps can be scored by different scoring methods.

How can I determine which scoring is the best (most reliable) for each school (e.g. traditional vs. waldorf school)?
I've read that G theory (generalizability theory) is applicable for similar cases, but i don't know how to apply for this case.

Comment: Can you please give some more context? What are these scoring methods? I doubt the question is answerable in its present form.